# how to call a makefile target it it contain variable name?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, makefile

If let's say target of makefile (i.e. `$(SESSION)/compiled.csh`) contains a variable name .. how can we call a makefile to run with that target ??

--------------calling makefile -------------------------

```
make \
     -f makefile  \
     session_name=rtl_unit \
```

---------------- makefile content ----------------------

```
ifeq ($(MAKECMDGOALS), all) 
 DEFAULT_DEP := dep1 dep2
else
 DEFAULT_DEP := dep1
endif*

export SESSION = $(TESTBENCH_PATH)/blocks/$(session_name)
$(SESSION)/compiled.csh : something
```

Comment: please format your question: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: `make /path/to/testbench/blocks/rtl_unit/compiled.csh`

Comment: Could you elaborate more ?

Comment: PATH (/path/to/testbench/blocks/rtl_unit/ ) is derived inside makefile based on some parameter .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another phony target and make it depend on your hard-to-spell target:

```
$(SESSION)/compiled.csh : something
compiled : $(SESSION)/compiled.csh
.PHONY: compiled
```

And then:

```
make compiled
```